# Kubuntu 16.04 window title bars keep disappearing

Tags: 16.04, crash, plasma

Using kubuntu 16.04. three days ago after an update title bars in windows started disappearing leaving the windows contents working fine... But no way to control them ( no close "X" for instance.

Login is fine, then the first window that comes up is fine. As soon as a second opens then poof everything vanishes...

Taskbar also occasionally disappearing and even when present clicking open progs on it does not raise them to the top of the stack..

I tried changing the theme but no joy. It's making the system totally unusable at present.

Anyone had a similar problem and know a fix ?

Help !

Answer (score 1):

So this is me answering my own question - but not with any real knowledge of why this worked. The clue was in a post about lightdm.....

I opened a terminal and entered my .config directory

> cd ~/.config

then my dconf directory

> cd dconf

there I deleted the user file

> rm user

rebooting the system came back up with titlebars and a working task switcher... Really no idea why it got corrupted.

To be honest I am getting sick of having to fix stuff like this just to use my pc... arghh!! maybe time to buy a mac!

Comment: Although I found this useful, throwing more money at Apple isn't the answer. Have you logged it (and the solution) as a bug?